# How do I add text boxes and buttons into a table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sorry, I'm new to Javascript and this is one of the first websites that I have made. I was wondering why exactly my code isn't working properly.

Instead of a text box and a button showing up, in the cells where they are supposed to show up, [object HTMLInputElement] and [object HTMLButtonElement] show up.

```
function frenchBread(x){
      var table = document.getElementById("orderTable");
      var row = table.insertRow(0);

      var rem = document.createElement("button");
      var name = document.createTextNode("Remove");
      rem.appendChild(name);  

      var num = document.createElement("input");

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

        cell1.innerHTML = "French Bread";
        cell2.innerHTML = document.body.appendChild(num);
        cell3.innerHTML = document.body.appendChild(rem);
        x.disabled = true;

  }


<button type = "button" class = "itemClick" onclick  = "frenchBread(this);">French Bread</button>

<table id = "orderTable">
</table>
```

Comment: can you add your HTML?

Comment: read more about **[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)**

Comment: What is the function parameter `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append your variables, no need to call `innerHTML`:

```
cell1.innerHTML = "French Bread";
cell2.appendChild(num);
cell3.appendChild(rem);
```

instead of:

```
cell1.innerHTML = "French Bread";
cell2.innerHTML = document.body.appendChild(num);
cell3.innerHTML = document.body.appendChild(rem);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eqynz586/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I added a little more HTML before making the adjustment to your code so that it can be run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button type = "button" class = "itemClick" onclick  = "frenchBread(this);">French Bread</button>
<table id="orderTable"></table>
<script>

function frenchBread(x){
  var table = document.getElementById("orderTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

  var rem = document.createElement("button");
  var name = document.createTextNode("Remove");
  rem.appendChild(name);  

  var num = document.createElement("input");

    cell1.innerHTML = "French Bread";
    cell2.appendChild(num);
    cell3.appendChild(rem);
    x.disabled = true;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason that your code was failing was that the text "French Bread) that you assigned to cel1's innerHTML is valid HTML.  innerHTML can only accept strings that are valid HTML.   While it did not work for cel2 and cel3 because rem and num were DOM elements.  therefore they can be assigned as children of the cel2 and cel3 (which are also DOM elements) by using the appendChild member functions of those two cell elements. Whe you tried to do that through the innerHTML  JavaScript had to convert those DOM elements into text, and so the text that you saw resulted from the JS object being converted into strings.